# How does a OS X Launch Agent persist settings/state?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm writing an OS X launch agent (which watches, as it happens, for FSEvents);
it therefore has no UI and is not started from a bundle – it's just a program.
The relevant [documentation and sample
code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/FileSystemEvents/_index.html)
illustrates persisting FS event IDs between invocations, and does so using
`NSUserDefaults`.  This is clear the Right Thing To Do(TM).

The documentation for `NSUserDefaults` in the
*Preferences and Settings Programming Guide*
would appear to be the appropriate thing to read.
This shows only the Application and Global domains as being persistent, but (fairly
obviously) only the Application domain is writable for an application.  However
the preferences in the application domain are keyed on the
ApplicationBundleIdentifier, which a launch agent won't have.  So I'm at a loss
how such an agent should persist state.

All I can think of is that the `Label` in the `launchd` job can act as the
ApplicationBundleIdentifier – it at least has the correct form.  But I can't see any
hint that that's correct, in the documentation.

The obvious (unix-normal) thing to do would be to write to a dot-file
in `$HOME`, but that's presumably not the Cocoa Way.  Google searches
on 'osx daemon preferences', and the like, don't show up anything useful,
or else my google-fu is sadly lacking today.  Googling for 'set application
bundle identifier' doesn't turn up anything likely, either.
`NSUserDefaults:persistentDomainForName` looks like it should be relevant,
but I can't work out its intentions from its method documentation.

I've found [one question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315048/) which seems relevant, but while it's tantalisingly close, it doesn't say where the daemon gets its identifier from.

I've limited experience with Objective-C and Cocoa, which means that by
now I rather suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree, but don't really know where
to look next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and imo should) have an Info.plist even in a single-file executable.(see http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2083/the-power-of-plist)

However, NSUserDefaults is a little more questionable. Conceptually, it's intended for user settings, rather than internal state. However, there's no real reason it wouldn't be suited to this, so I'd probably go ahead and do so.

Comment: Thanks: that `__info_plist` section appears to be near-folklore! – I can't seem to find any apple.com documentation on it.  Interestingly the [code signing docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html) note that "[a]lthough single-file tools don’t normally have an Info.plist, you can add one."  It sounds plausible (and I'll experiment), but that remark makes me think I'm missing something. Using the 'settings' interface for persisting state surprised me, too, but it's what's exemplified in the FSEvents sample code.

Comment: This works: I set [CFBundleIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1) in a `Info.plist` XML file, and linked this in with the flag `-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist Info.plist`. This successfully produced a preferences file which persisted application state, and which would allow me to make other application settings.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Sorry to bump this, but here's what I tried. Instantiated a NSUserDefaults with the contentsOfFile of my /Users/username/Library/Preferences/app.plist this worked while logged in, but not while my app is running in the login screen as a LaunchAgent. The things is, my app needs to read values in UserDefaults that may change, for this reason, I don't think I can embed a plist into my .app and read/write to it there, can I? Where should my app write so that it can read while logged out as a LaunchAgent? Thanks